# Figure(s) is in plural instead of singular

Tags: floats

The text below a figure (in all of my figures) states "figures" in plural instead of singular. How can I edit the plural into singular? okay, so these are all the codes I used that "include" something with figures:

```
\documentclass[12pt,chapterprefix]{scrreprt} % for bigger size of text 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listfigurename}{Figures}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listtablename}{Tables}                            
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figures}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that replicates this behaviour (since it's not the norm)? Your minimal example should be code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and allow us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. Can you do that?

Comment: you have asked many questions now and and been asked on most to provide an example. This one is completely impossible to understand as it is.

Comment: perhaps you want `\renewcommand\figurename{Figure}` but that is the default definition, so it is really impossible to guess your issue.

Comment: If you ask LaTeX to label “Figures” every figure caption, that's what it does.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious "replace `Figures` by `Figure`" in the code you showed?

Comment: no, I haven't tried yet. The first "Figures" belongs to the tables right? The last to listoffigures?

Comment: yes, it worked, the last code belonged to figure(s) (the illustrations). thx

Answer (score 2):

Remove `\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}`. `\listtablesname` is already renamed to »Tables« by

```latex
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listtablename}{Tables}
```

If you really want to rename `\figuresname` (the label for figures in the document) use `\renewcaptionname`. Here is an example redefining `figuresname` to »Fig.«:

```latex
\renewcaptionname{english}{\figurename}{Fig.}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listfigurename}{Figures}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listtablename}{Tables}

\renewcaptionname{english}{\figurename}{Fig.}% <- 

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\chapter{Foo}
\begin{figure}[hbp]
  \centering
  \rule{5cm}{1cm}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Bar}
\begin{table}[hbp]
  \centering
  \rule{5cm}{1cm}
  \caption{A table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]